# Calculating the distance between Centroid and Point

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I am a college student trying to finish a project in ArcMap; I have no professional training and am at a loss.  I need to calculate the distance, in miles, from the centroid of polygons to a specific point.  I have made this point a shapefile.  I think I should be using Python, but I am not sure what expression to use.

Comment: dont just downvote the question people, tell the person why this answer is not up too par

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 3):

to generate centroids:

http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/feature-to-point.htm

to determine distance between centroids and points:

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/point-distance.htm

Comment: Since the latter links to a deprecated tool, I'd suggest Near / Generate Near Table.